# Excel Power Query Error - Expression.Error: The argument value isn't valid

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, power-query, microsoft-powerbi

I'm trying to copy sheets from one workbook to another by copy and pasting the queries. These queries work fine in the original sheet but when I copy them, I get an error

```
Expression.Error: The Argument Name isn't Valid. Details: List
```

The query being done is:

```
 let
    Source = #"Base Table",
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(Source,null,0,Replacer.ReplaceValue,List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Value.Is(Value.FromText(_), type date))),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Replaced Value", List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value"), each not Value.Is(Value.FromText(_), type date)), "Date", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{{"Date", type date}, {"Value", type number}}),

    #"Filtered Rows1" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Value] <> 0),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows1", "Custom", each [Value] * [Billable Rate]),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", "Monetary Value"}}),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Group", "Region", "Level", "Name", "Client", "Mandate", "Mandate Code", "Billable? (Y/N) ", "Status", "Recovery", "Billable Rate", "Date", "Value", "Monetary Value"}),
    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Removed Other Columns", dates})
in
    #"Appended Query"
```

The sheet is called Sheet 8 in the copied workbook and Period Totals in another. There are a couple of other queries with connections to an external database in the new workbook but not in the original one - could that be an issue?

Any thoughts on how I can debug/resolve this? Not sure what's causing it - is it an excel bug? Thank you!!

Comment: Please post the query you used, the sheet name, and such, so we can give accurate suggestion to you

Comment: Edited my question with some more information, thanks!

Comment: @Vylix forgot to tag you in the above comment

Comment: On what step do you see the error in?

Comment: Did you copy the Query object from the Queries pane in the Query Editor window, or did you create a new blank query and copy in the Query code?  The first method is more reliable as it includes any dependent objects.

Answer (score -1):

I would copy the Query object from the Queries pane in the Query Editor window. That method is more reliable as it includes any dependent objects.